# Can I use Google Sheets to Automatically Update Font Styling, Size, Color, etc.?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have been creating a contact list in Google Sheets to continually add and update names, emails, organizations, etc. for work. I am often copying and pasting this information from other sources as to avoid typoes. I know I can paste as special, though at times I am copying and pasting a handful of entries and this would take more time than I would like. Is there any way to have a script automatically change the font styling of a cell (size, bold, background, typeface, etc.) if it doesn't match the default?

Answer (score 1):

You can use macro that records your desired font, size, cell color etc. It's a script that don't need coding. You may check more info on this [link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7665004?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Found in: `Tools > Macros > Record Macro`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need a script at all.

**You can use Shift-Ctrl-V instead of Ctrl-V to match the target styling.** I do this all the time. As long as you're comfortable with keyboard shortcuts, it's significantly faster than doing Edit > Paste special > ... - in fact, just as fast as regular Ctrl-V :)

You can also **paste stuff in however you normally do, and then use Ctrl-\ to undo all formatting** (at which point it'll just be plain Arial 10pt, or whatever), **and then bulk change afterwards, once you've cleaned up the text** -- at first glance this option doesn't really answer your question, but I've found that in some cases the first "cleaning-up" of data after it's been pasted in can be easier to do with a bare bones look.